# Neo4j java high cpu usage remains 392%

Tags: java, memory-management, neo4j, cpu-usage

I am running the neo4j server on Linux machine 16Gb RAM and 4 cores and the total number of nodes in my DB is 342860 and total no of relationship is 1647619, I am trying to debug the problem so I have stopped all neo4j related processing (read & write).

But CPU usage for neo4j java process is still 400%, 100/core as I am having 4 cores.

Due to character limit restriction i was not able to paste whole log here so i have added pastebin url in comments.

I tried to see the stack of java process using jstack , following contains is the log of it

```
Attaching to process ID 8458, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.111-b14
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 8536: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=57, line=389 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll() @bci=12, line=531 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$700(org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool) @bci=1, line=47 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run() @bci=300, line=590 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8531: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=49, line=418 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.concurrent.RunnableBoltWorker.run() @bci=28, line=88 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)



Thread 8529: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=49, line=418 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.concurrent.RunnableBoltWorker.run() @bci=28, line=88 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8525: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=49, line=418 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.concurrent.RunnableBoltWorker.run() @bci=28, line=88 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)



Thread 8510: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.run() @bci=19, line=152 (Interpreted frame)
 - io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run() @bci=4, line=144 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8509: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(long, int, long, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(long) @bci=18, line=269 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(long) @bci=28, line=93 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(long) @bci=37, line=86 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(long) @bci=30, line=97 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(boolean) @bci=91, line=746 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run() @bci=56, line=391 (Interpreted frame)
 - io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run() @bci=44, line=858 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8507: (state = IN_JAVA)
Error occurred during stack walking:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:88)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:66)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)


Thread 8506: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=57, line=389 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll() @bci=12, line=531 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$700(org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool) @bci=1, line=47 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run() @bci=300, line=590 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8504: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8463: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 8503: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8502: (state = IN_JAVA)
 - org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.StoreNodeRelationshipCursor.next() @bci=662, line=168 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.CursorRelationshipIterator.nextCursor() @bci=11, line=52 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.CursorRelationshipIterator.hasNext() @bci=9, line=67 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.BeansAPIRelationshipIterator.hasNext() @bci=4, line=41 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.CachingExpandInto$$anon$1.fetchNextOrNull() @bci=4, line=95 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.CachingExpandInto$$anon$1.fetchNextOrNull() @bci=1, line=90 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek() @bci=14, line=60 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext() @bci=1, line=46 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext() @bci=4, line=42 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(scala.collection.Iterator) @bci=1, line=330 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty() @bci=1, line=1336 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.ExpandIntoPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.ExecutionContext) @bci=99, line=64 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.ExpandIntoPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(java.lang.Object) @bci=5, line=53 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur() @bci=14, line=434 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext() @bci=27, line=440 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(scala.collection.Iterator) @bci=1, line=330 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty() @bci=1, line=1336 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.SemiApplyPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.ExecutionContext) @bci=34, line=34 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.SemiApplyPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(java.lang.Object) @bci=5, line=31 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext() @bci=40, line=463 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext() @bci=11, line=461 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(scala.collection.Iterator, scala.Function1) @bci=1, line=893 (Compiled frame)
 - scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(scala.Function1) @bci=2, line=1336 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.EagerAggregationPipe.internalCreateResults(scala.collection.Iterator, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState) @bci=78, line=89 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState) @bci=26, line=82 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState) @bci=5, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState) @bci=5, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState) @bci=5, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState) @bci=5, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState) @bci=5, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState) @bci=5, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState) @bci=5, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.createResults(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.QueryState, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.ExecutionMode, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.v3_2.phases.InternalNotificationLogger) @bci=107, line=96 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.build(java.lang.Object, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.ExecutionMode, scala.collection.immutable.Map, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.v3_2.phases.InternalNotificationLogger) @bci=138, line=74 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.spi.QueryContext, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.ExecutionMode, scala.collection.immutable.Map) @bci=178, line=103 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) @bci=13, line=86 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anon$1.run(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.spi.QueryContext, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.ExecutionMode, scala.collection.immutable.Map) @bci=7, line=55 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.Compatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply() @bci=37, line=102 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.Compatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply() @bci=1, line=100 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.exceptionHandler$runSafely$.apply(scala.Function0, scala.Function1) @bci=1, line=90 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.Compatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v3_2.TransactionalContextWrapper, org.neo4j.cypher.internal.CypherExecutionMode, scala.collection.immutable.Map) @bci=92, line=100 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.PreparedPlanExecution.execute(org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v3_2.TransactionalContextWrapper, scala.collection.immutable.Map) @bci=19, line=26 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionEngine.execute(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.TransactionalContext) @bci=85, line=107 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.executeQuery(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.TransactionalContext) @bci=11, line=61 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.safelyExecute(org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.Statement, boolean, org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.TransactionalContext) @bci=13, line=371 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.executeStatements(org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.StatementDeserializer, org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.ExecutionResultSerializer, java.util.List, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) @bci=129, line=323 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.commit(org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.StatementDeserializer, org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.ExecutionResultSerializer, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) @bci=53, line=157 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService.lambda$executeStatementsAndCommit$1(org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle, java.io.InputStream, java.net.URI, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, java.io.OutputStream) @bci=47, line=217 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService$$Lambda$300.write(java.io.OutputStream) @bci=21 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput, java.lang.Class, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[], javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType, javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, java.io.OutputStream) @bci=3, line=71 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[], javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType, javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, java.io.OutputStream) @bci=15, line=57 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write() @bci=514, line=302 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext, com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest, com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse) @bci=234, line=1510 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest, com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse) @bci=23, line=1419 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest, com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseWriter) @bci=14, line=1409 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(java.net.URI, java.net.URI, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=76, line=409 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(java.net.URI, java.net.URI, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=9, line=558 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=355, line=733 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=39, line=790 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=89, line=808 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=211, line=1669 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationEnabledFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) @bci=274, line=122 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=103, line=1652 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) @bci=54, line=69 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=103, line=1652 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=203, line=585 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=46, line=221 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=349, line=1127 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=274, line=515 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=233, line=185 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=437, line=1061 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=20, line=141 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=39, line=52 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=23, line=97 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel) @bci=130, line=497 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle() @bci=301, line=310 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable() @bci=189, line=257 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run() @bci=4, line=540 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=1, line=635 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run() @bci=75, line=555 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)



Thread 8490: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst() @bci=22, line=492 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.take() @bci=1, line=680 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.take() @bci=8, line=118 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.io.fs.watcher.DefaultFileSystemWatcher.startWatching() @bci=16, line=76 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.io.fs.watcher.RestartableFileSystemWatcher.startWatching() @bci=41, line=94 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.watcher.DefaultFileSystemWatcherService$FileSystemEventWatcher.run() @bci=7, line=92 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8489: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=100, line=1088 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.helpers.NamedThreadFactory$2.run() @bci=1, line=109 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8488: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.parkEvictor(long) @bci=7, line=840 (Compiled frame)
 - org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.parkUntilEvictionRequired(int) @bci=12, line=894 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.continuouslySweepPages() @bci=21, line=875 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.EvictionTask.run(org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache) @bci=1, line=39 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.BackgroundTask.run() @bci=68, line=45 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8487: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.neo4j.helpers.NamedThreadFactory$2.run() @bci=1, line=109 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8486: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop() @bci=201, line=552 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.run() @bci=1, line=505 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8485: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.poll(int, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.access$600(int, int) @bci=2, line=47 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run() @bci=10, line=314 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8479: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 8478: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 8477: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=59, line=143 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=164 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=36, line=209 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8476: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=502 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(boolean) @bci=54, line=191 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=1, line=153 (Interpreted frame)
```

Can anyone please help me out to debug/solve this issue of high cpu usage of neo4j.

Comment: full log stack pastebin url https://pastebin.com/rvd8eWCP

Comment: There is one update for others reference, I am still not sure what is the real cause for this issue, but I removed all unnecessary relationships from the DB and now CPU usage is normal. I will update the answer once I will found the actual issue.

Comment: In the future, you should provide (important snippets of) your code. It is difficult (or impossible) to tell what is going on just by looking at a dump of thread callstacks.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, after a week of debugging, It turned out that, we haven't created any index on our node's property and it was causing this much high CPU usage.

After creation of the index, our CPU usage has gone down to 0.3 % from 400 and we have degraded our machine from 16 GB, 4 cores to 8Gb, 2 cores as well.

Please make sure to create the index on the property and unique constraints where it needed.

Comment: Hey, I'm experiencing the same symptoms although I have indexes on relevant properties.
Do you have any idea why?

Comment: you must be missing an index on a property, recheck the code and go through all the properties.

Comment: This is a query:
Match (n:LABEL1 {myid: 1})
Match (n1: LABEL2 {myid: 2})
SET n._lock = 1
SET n1._lock = 1
Merge (n)-[:RLABEL]->(n1)

I have index on:
:LABEL1(myid),  :LABEL2(myid)